# Broken Partition table

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, fdisk

So I have a ssd disk and somehow the GPT partition table got removed.

From that moment, when I plug disk in, disk is still connected (image below) but when I try to access it through diskpart, it's not visible (second image below).
I also tried to use arch installation media, did fdisk and wrote partition table, but when i tried it again, it said the table is missing. Also, archinstall program says unknown partition table.

[image: Disk is connected]

[image: Image not visible on diskpart]

Comment: Also, archinstall program says unknown partition table

Comment: The drive may be dead. Also [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/53467)

Comment: The disk is not dead, it can save data trough hxd so its not dead